# Square API: How does the payment notifications webhook work?

Tags: square-connect

I recently inherited an app that uses the Webhooks from the Connect API. I'm looking through this:

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#webhooks-overview

I have the webhook setup with what it says in the docs:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: 
application/json" -d "[\"PAYMENT_UPDATED\"]" 
https://connect.squareup.com/v1/LOCATION_ID/webhooks
```

I recently had an issue where I was receiving 2 requests for each `PAYMENT_UPDATED` event. I eventually found out that this was because 2 separate accounts had the webhook enabled. The two accounts were

1) a developer's account

2) the client's account

However, what I don't understand is how the developer's account was receiving notifications for the orders coming from the client's account?

Is it because it hooks up any orders placed in the location (which comes from the `LOCATION_ID`) and the webhook URL specified for the merchant (which is identified by the  `PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN`)? This works even if the merchant is not the owner of that location?

Comment: When you say "developer's account", is this a totally distinct merchant account, or an account set up as an employee of the merchant?

Comment: Honestly I am unsure (the developer left). However, I do have access to another account (developer #2) that I know is hooked up to this "client account"'s orders. How would I check if this account is set up as an employee of the merchant?

Comment: When you log in as the merchant, you should be able to see all the employees, and see if the developers are in there. Since it is possible to create highly permissioned "employee" roles, you can essentially have multiple admins for a square account.

Comment: Hm when I log into my client's account I don't see either of the developer's accounts.

Comment: Will do! Writing it now

Answer (score 0):

You probably have multiple applications connected to your account with the same notification URL, so you are getting notified twice. If you go to https://squareup.com/dashboard/apps/my-apps you can see the apps that are authoirzed for a given account and remove ones that you aren't using anymore.